# How to connect the neighborhood vertices

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, vertices

I have the number of vertices's having random position.Now i want to connect that vertices's to form the graph as shown in this [figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aOctahedron_graph.png) ,this graph is based on [neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28graph_theory%29#Neighbourhood_of_a_Set) graph theory.I want to write the application in `JAVA`.

Is there any algorithm to find out neighboring vertices's?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  What does it mean to say that two vertices are neighbouring?  The link that you've provided doesn't specify that.

Comment: I have just edited my question.

Comment: Right, but there still isn't enough information.  You see, of the six vertices, each one is connected to four of the five others; so there are three pairs of vertices, where the vertices within each pair are not connected to each other.  But if the six vertices have random positions, there's not enough information to determine how to pair them off.

Comment: please suggest any way to connect the points in such manner to form the graph as shown in the figure.

Comment: You mean you don't want edges to cross?

Comment: If you mean you want to be able to connect six random points, to make a planar embedding of the octohedral graph, with line segments for edges, then you are doomed to fail.  This is not generally possible.  The reason why it's not generally possible would be off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you could try posting your question on Mathematics.SE.